# sequelize to create better database structure

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, rdbms

i am trying to think of a database for a project similar to netflix. where you can login on multiple devices and for each device you have a token.

the problem is that i cannot think of a structure of a relational database for that.

i created it on mongodb and my structure was like that:

```
{
  user: 'name',
  etc...
  tokens: [{
    token: 'asdasijdoaisjd',
    token: 'sodjio2n'
  }]
}
```

so yeah... everytime a user logins in a new token gets added to the db and when he logs out from one place, one token gets deleted.

how can i create something similar in a relational database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is two ways to do that

1. add a column in your users table called `tokens` for example and save all of the tokens as `JSON` data
2. [**Recomended**] make a new table called `users_tokens` and make a relation of on to many between the user to tokens table and in the `users_tokens` table you will add a column called `user_id` to easily get all tokens that belong to the `user`

[image]

At last, you can read about how to implement `one-to-many` relation with sequelize [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#one-to-many-relationships)

Comment: I'd prefer point 2 because tokens are changed much more frequently comparing to a user itself.

Comment: yah i agree with you it would be more easily to manage and edit

Comment: ok i made both, using one-to-many and not using it. And i dont understand whats the point of using it. Cuz i can set the userId of the tokens to be the userid whenever i create a new token. So if i wanna manage the user tokens i manage via the userid. whats the point of creating the one-to-many relation?

Comment: @nishi when you create a column `userid` in another table this called one-to-many but when you create a foreign key it will add more validation layer in case if you forget to add it

Comment: alright ive done that. But, it means that it is not super required to explicitly do: "Tokens.hasMany(User); User.belongsTo(Tokens)" ?

Comment: in `sequelize` it will add for you more functionality that will help you with it's powerfull ORM system.

Comment: If you will not wish to get a user long with his/her tokens then you don't need to add association User.hasMany(Tokens) as well as you don't need to add Tokens.belongsTo(User) if you don't want to load a user of a given token.